# Position sticky with flex-direction column reverse

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky

I am trying to create a sticky central element with flex-direction column-reverse. Using flex-direction column works fine. Is this possible with column-reverse?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
    /*  works with flex-direction: column;   */
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.child, .sticky {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: gold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.sticky {
  background: crimson;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="sticky"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the purpose of column-reverse since your elements seems to be all the same?

Comment: it's an example - I need flex-direction column reverse for infinite scroll loading direction up...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We just add the one div `.child-parent` in the parent div and set flex properties according to solve your problem.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.child-parent {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  position: relative;
}

.child,
.sticky {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: gold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.sticky {
  width: 100%;
  background: crimson;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child-parent">
            <div class="child">1</div>
            <div class="child">2</div>
            <div class="child">3</div>
            <div class="child">4</div>
            <div class="child">5</div>
            <div class="child">6</div>
            <div class="child">7</div>
            <div class="child">8</div>
            <div class="child">9</div>
            <div class="child">10</div>
            <div class="sticky"></div>
            <div class="child">11</div>
            <div class="child">12</div>
            <div class="child">13</div>
            <div class="child">14</div>
            <div class="child">15</div>
            <div class="child">16</div>
            <div class="child">17</div>
            <div class="child">18</div>
            <div class="child">19</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We have edit our code to resolve the issue for the safari browser. Hope it will work now.

Comment: Unfortunately the reason I want column-reverse is so that loading more items above keeps the scroll in place. The `parent-child` container from your example breaks the load more behaviour in safari. For clarification, open https://codesandbox.io/s/stick-central-element-column-reverse-sticky-of4yt?file=/src/App.tsx:775-792 in safari. Scroll down to the sticky element. Click "load more array1" note how the sticky element moves down. This is undesirable. For comparison, see the desired behaviour: https://codesandbox.io/s/stick-central-element-column-reverse-simple-bysnc?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: As per your reference, we edit our code. Can you please check the updated code?

Comment: it doesn't works. you can see it running the snippet